# How do I interface python progam with the web

Tags: python, html

I have a python program and need to run that program in the background and get the output in the browser .we are using a plug-in for this purpose and I found that only html and Java script can be run in chrome extension.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to build a web application?  If so, [web.py](http://webpy.org/) is my personal favorite.  It's very lightweight and easy to use.

Here's an entire web application -- albeit a trivial one.

```
import web

urls = (
    '/(.*)', 'hello'
)
app = web.application(urls, globals())

class hello:        
    def GET(self, name):
        if not name: 
            name = 'World'
        return 'Hello, ' + name + '!'

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```